# Does the Stieltjes integral $ \int_{0} ^{4} x^{2} d([x^{2}])$ exists? if it exists, find its value.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Does the Stieltjes integral $ \int_{0} ^{4} x^{2} d([x^{2}])$ exists? if it exists, find its value.

I already showed that it exists: $f(x)=x^{2}$ is continuous and increasing in $[0,4]$, $\alpha (x)=[x^{2}]$, the whole major function, is increasing in $[0,4]$. So, $f\in R(\alpha)$ in $[0,4]$. I have difficulty finding its value.

Comment: Have you tried to find it by the definition?

Comment: $\int_{0} ^{4} x^{2} d([x^{2}])=\int_{0} ^{4} x^{2} x dx=\dfrac{4^4}{4}=64.$

Comment: @Yngwie Malmsteen No. I computed it using reduction of a Riemann-Stieltjes integral to a finite sum. I found the value of 136 but I'm not sure.

Comment: Cut the interval at points really close to the integers. The integrals along the subintervals that don't contain roots of integers are going to be zero. For example $\int_{1+\epsilon}^{\sqrt{2}-\epsilon}x^2d([x^2])=\int_{1+\epsilon}^{\sqrt{2}-\epsilon}x^2d(1)=\int_{1+\epsilon}^{\sqrt{2}-\epsilon}x^20d(x)=0$.Then compute the integral at the little intervals that do contain roots of integers by the definition. Use cuts in which the root of integer point is a cutting point is an evaluation point between two cutting points, for comfort.

Comment: @Jean Marie $[x^{2}]$ is the greatest integer function. Is not $x^{2}$

Comment: @miguel All right. But think to mention this convention $\[ \ \]$= integer part because there is no universal acceptance for this notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The function $[x^2]$ is piecewise constant with jump discontinuities at $x=\sqrt{k}$ for integer $k$. The size of each jump equals $1$ and the value of the integrand $x^2$ at the $k$th jump equals $k$. Thus

$$\int_0^4 x^2 d[x^2] = \sum_{k=1}^{16} k\cdot 1 = 136.$$

Comment: Who has put $-1$ to this answer, can explain why this is not correct? 136 is the result I mentioned in a previous comment. But I was not sure.

Comment: @miguel Somebody put that vote on the previous version of my answer in which I had misread the question. This answer is correct.

Comment: It wasn't me . I gave you +1 just now. I think -1 voters should be required to identify themselves.